# Can maven assembly produce a file without the format suffix

Tags: maven, maven-assembly-plugin, cloudera-manager

I've managed to get maven assembly to produce a custom NAME-assemblyId.tar.gz, but I actually want to name the final result just NAME-assemblyId, without the format suffix.

No combination of finalName and appendAssemblyId can fix this it seems?

Currently I'm using a copy mojo to rename it after packaging, but that is not ideal, I guess I could also use a attach-artifact mojo to attach them though.

Comment: Do you need that artifact for deploying into a repository or only during the build?

Comment: I need to deploy it as well.

Answer (score 2):

Set appendAssemblyId to false in your assembly configuration

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>jar-with-dep</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <configuration>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
                <finalName>com.activee.migration.cli</finalName>
                <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
                <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>cli-zip</id> 
            <phase>package</phase> 
            <configuration>
                <descriptors>
                  <descriptor>src/main/assembly/cli_zip.xml</descriptor>
                </descriptors>
                <finalName>com.activee.migration.cli</finalName>
                <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
                <goal>single</goal> 
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
```